# How do I call a jquery function for a dynamic ID?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to call a function on click for a image that has a dynamic ID. How do I do it. I am new to JQuery. I have seen other posts that are related to calling a function using the ID but I can't find one that has a dynamic ID.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: You can do with `class`. Please describe more specific problem with a code.

Comment: The question is, why do you have an ID that you can't access, and where are these ID's coming from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that the ID of the element is not necessarily known, you could give it a specific class and reference it by that instead.

HTML:

```
<div id="Canbeanything" class="wellknownclassname"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.wellknownclassname').click(function() {
    // do whatever
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know what the dynamic ID is going to be, then you can just make a string of whatever the ID is and pass that to the jQuery selector. So say that you wanted to dynamically select a bunch of divs with the IDs `div1` ... `divn`:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    $element = $('#div' + i);
    // do whatever to the element
}
```

Using jQuery's selector, you're just passing it a string, so you can create that string however you want. Now if you don't KNOW the dynamic ID, then there's obviously no way to select something by ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have a variable with the id name you can simply pass the variable to jquery, prefixed with a hash:

```
function highlightDiv(id) {
    $("#" + id).addClass("highlight");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a crazy unique class name and attach it to it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="randomgeneratedid" class="crazyuniqueclassname"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.crazyuniqueclassname').click(function() {
    // Your Code
});
```